# Why are $U$ and $V$ (and not $N$) the only extensive parameters for blackbody radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, thermal-radiation, quantum-statistics

In Chapter 3.6 of Callen, he remarks that the particle number $N$ does not appear in the thermodynamic description of blackbody radiation. Why is this? That is, in most simple systems of one component, the fundamental equation is a function of $U,N,V$: $S = S(U,N,V)$. Here, however, we have $S = S(U,V)$.

In the quantum statistical mechanics language I am familiar with, would one say that this is because the corresponding number operator $\hat{N}$ is not a constant of the motion? And is this, in turn, because of absorption and reradation from the walls?

Comment: Oh, you are progressing towards the more fun parts of Callen! I'm so happy~

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I hope all is well -- indeed I am! Incidentally, if you are able to look at my question about mercury thermometers I would also appreciate that.

Answer (score 4):

In a system of photons the *number* $N$ of photons is not constrained, hence, in equilibrium $N$ will take a value that minimizes the free energy $F$, that is
$$\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial N}\right)_{T,V}=0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

But this partial derivative in $\eqref{1}$ is the chemical potential $\mu$ associated with the photon number. Therefore in the equation $dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN$ the term $dN$ can be left out for it plays no role.

Comment: At this point in the text $F$ has not been introduced; is there an argument (perhaps more fundamental?) which does not make use of it? I was thinking something along the lines of the operator $\hat{N}$ not being a constant of the motion for photons in a box?

Comment: Callen writes: "If the walls of any "empty" vessel are maintained at a temperature $T$ it
is found that the vessel is, in fact, the repository of electromagnetic energy, etc." The natural potential of a thermodynamic system in contact  with a single  constant temperature reservoir is the free energy. But since $dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN$ all you have to know is that now $d(U-TS)=-pdV+\mu dN$ and this kind of non-thermal equilibrium is with its own associated "mechanical" energy minimum. Note: photons do not move in the box, photons are discrete quanta of energy in absorption and emission.

Comment: Sorry, when I say constant of the motion I just mean that it's an operator which commutes with the system Hamiltonian (quantum sense of constant of motion). I will have to think a bit more about your answer but I feel like it's missing something at the core of the theory -- part of the essence of equilibrium thermo seems to me in the choice of macroscopic parameters/data to describe a system, and I feel like this question has to do with that rather than anything within the theory proper.

Comment: I do not know of any real application of the Hamiltonian formalism in classical (not statistical) thermodynamics, there may be one, I just have not seen. You are right though that $F$ appears later in the book, to which I would say Callen, who died 30 years ago, had made a pedagogical error, but it is unlikely that anybody would rewrite and republish it with corrections, and there are also many typos in it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple fluid system, e.g. nitrogen gas in a container, stating temperature $T$ and volume $V$ is not enough to completely describe its thermodynamic state, because there are many different macrostates which share the same $T,V$, and differ in the number of particles $N$. We can prepare such different state from an initial state $T_0,V_0,N_0$ by adding more particles $\Delta N$ into the container, while keeping temperature constant by means of a heat reservoir.

With equilibrium radiation, this is not so; stating $T,V$ already completely describes its thermodynamic state, it implies its energy $U$, and there is no further macroscopic degree of freedom. This can be taken as experimental fact; radiation can't be added or removed from a system of equilibrium radiation at constant temperature like matter can. When we add some radiation via small hole in the wall from the outside, this will change temperature inside, and any attempt to bring the temperature back will also remove the corresponding "amount" of radiation, so the system will get back to the state it was in, not a different state.

This is related to the fact the intensity of equilibrium radiation and thus (assuming Poynting's formulae) also energy density of equilibrium radiation is function of temperature only; it does not depend on chemical composition of the matter interacting with the radiation, or amount of this matter, or the way the radiation intensity was increased in the past. It is *universal*.

In quantum theory of free radiation in the cavity, if the radiation is in thermodynamic equilibrium and the cavity size does not change, the number operator $\hat{N}_{\lambda \mathbf k}$ has constant expectation value $\langle \hat{N}_{\lambda \mathbf k} \rangle$, so "average number of photons" is constant. When we move slowly and isothermically one wall of the cavity so its volume $V$ diminishes, radiation intensity will remain the same (due to temperature being the same), and energy will decrease proportionally to volume $V$. Thus the average number of photons will decrease proportionally to $V$. Thus $\langle \hat{N}_{\lambda \mathbf k} \rangle$ is not independent of $V$, in isothermal processes $\langle \hat{N}_{\lambda \mathbf k} \rangle$ is linear function of $V$. Thus in equilibrium thermodynamics we can ignore $\langle \hat{N}_{\lambda \mathbf k} \rangle$ for all $\lambda, \mathbf k$, as long as we take into account $V$.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this answer --I think in the last paragraph in particular you are getting at the $\hat{N}$ observable not being a constant of the motion?

Comment: No, there is no $\hat{N}$ in classical thermodynamics (which my answer is based on). And in quantum theory of radiation in a closed cavity, $\hat{N}_{\lambda,\mathbf{k}} = a_{\lambda,\mathbf{k}}^\dagger a_{\lambda,\mathbf{k}}$ is a constant of motion (commutes with free radiation Hamiltonian).

Comment: I see. So fair enough, within the framework of classical thermodynamics it is enough to say that $U,V$ completely characterize the state. But would it be possible to explain how this emerges in terms of a more fundamental theory (statistical mechanics, and in particular the information-theoretical/Jaynesian approach)? This is what I was trying to get at here -- if $\hat{N}$ were *not* a constant of the motion then I could resolve this (since in the information-theoretical approach, equilibrium states are characterized precisely...

Comment: ... by the constants of the motion), but I guess you are saying that claim is not true. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've added a paragraph on QT.